# Rotate a label around its center

Tags: rotation, label, titanium, center

I am trying to rotate a label around its center and have the following code. However, it's not getting rotated around its center, but around the view. How can I fix this problem?

```
var singleLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    backgroundColor:'red',
    text: i+1,
    top: 100,
    width: 35,
    height:20,
});

singleLabel.setAnchorPoint({x: 0,y:0});
var rotateFirst = Titanium.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate(270);
singleLabel.transform = rotateFirst;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anchor point of a Titanium view is defined like this :

[image]

- the **x property** match the **x axe**
- the **y property** match the **y axe**

Thus, if you want to rotate a view/label/... around it's center, you have to use `{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }` as anchor point.

If you want to convince yourself, you can play with this code :

```
var self = Ti.UI.createView();

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:        'Reference text',
    color:       '#000000',
    borderColor: '#000000'
});
self.add(label);

var label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:        'Reference text',
    color:       '#FF0000',
    borderColor: '#FF0000'
});
self.add(label2);

var rotation = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix({rotate: 90});
label2.setAnchorPoint({x: 1,y:1});
label2.transform = rotation;
```